A "magical" grid progression
Task: fill in the final grid correctly.
Hint, if it wasn't obvious enough already:

 The title and shape of the grids should be suggestive of something. Also, the line weights are relevant.


Are the thicknesses of the boxes relevant?

@Someone Yes. Check the hint.

If the bottom right of grid 3 was shaded, I think I'd have the solution, but since it isn't, I'm running into problems.

@AxiomaticSystem Damn, the puzzle was somehow messed up despite me proofreading it at least 4 times. I've fixed it now.

The final grid should be shaded

 in the central cell and the four edge cells

because

 the four grids are groups of binary digits.
 If the 8-point-lined grid displays 8's, the 4-point-lined grid displays 4's, the 2-point-lined displays 2's and the 1-point-lined grid displays 1's, then combining the four grids yields the numbers:
2 7 6
9 5 1
4 3 8
which form a magic square!


it took me a while, but i get it now. whew!  +1

The line weights aren't actually proportional, but you got the implied message. Good job!
